# Call Thread.yield() or equivalent from C (NDK)

Tags: android, c++, c, multithreading, android-ndk

I have a an AsyncTask in Android 2.3.3 with SDK 2.2.

Within the task/class I am utilizing a C-library with the NDK.

Instead of having a `while(condition)` loop in Java, I have this loop in C to avoid expensive calls via JNI during each loop iteration.

If I had the `while(condition)` loop in Java I would call `Thread.yield()` at the end of each loop-iteration to allow the Thread to get suspended.

Is there a possibility in C to get the same behaviour?
I tried it with `usleep(10)` at the the end of the `while(condition)` loop in C but I did not get the expected behaviour.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to add the C tag to your question so people who subscribe to that will see it.

Comment: I don't know about android, but mind you, that on some platforms "Thread.yield()", "sched_yield()", "pthread_yield()", "Sleep(0)", or whatever, is actually a noop.

Answer (score 3):

If one really wants to call Thread.yield() from C-Code one could do the following:

```
Java_de_company_MyClass_setupJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {

    (...snip...)

    jclass threadClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Thread");
    jmethodID yieldFunctionID = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, threadClass, "yield", "()V");

    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, threadClass, yieldFunctionID);

    (...snip...)    
}
```

Don't forget error checking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sched_yield()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html)

(edited after Steven Bell's comment)

Comment: Android doesn't have pthread_yield(); you have to use the POSIX sched_yield() instead.